# Removing unnecessary list brackets inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
n ={'b': [['a'], ['c']], 'a': [['c', 'b'], ['c']], 'c': [['b']]}
```

and require the following output:

```
n ={'b': ['a', 'c'], 'a': ['c', 'b'], 'c': ['b']}
```

I tried to use `itertools` and `join` but couldn't get it to work, can anyone help out?

Comment: `{k: list(set(chain.from_iterable(i))) for k, i in n.items()}` if you need unique values or `{k: list(chain.from_iterable(i)) for k, i in n.items()}` if you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) from `itertools` to combine these:

```
from itertools import chain

from_it = chain.from_iterable
{k: list(from_it(i)) for k, i in n.items()}
```

If you require unique values in the lists (which according to the title you don't), you can additionally wrap the result of `from_it` in a `set`.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate the dict and ignore the irrelevant list.

For uniqueness you can cast each inner_list to a `set`

```
n ={'b': [['a', 'b'], ['c']], 'a': [['c', 'b'], ['c']], 'c': [['b']]}

new_n = {}

for k,v in n.items():
  n[k] = [inner_item for item in v for inner_item in item]

print (n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import chain

n ={'b': [['a'], ['c']], 'a': [['c', 'b'], ['c']], 'c': [['b']]}

new_n = {a:list(set(chain(*[i[0] if len(i) == 1 else i for i in b]))) for a, b in n.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'a': ['c', 'b'], 'c': ['b'], 'b': ['a', 'c']}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `sum`:

```
>>> {k: sum(v, []) for k, v in n.items()}
{'a': ['c', 'b', 'c'], 'b': ['a', 'c'], 'c': ['b']}
```

> ```
> sum(iterable, start=0, /)
> ```
>
> Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers

Therefore, using an empty list as start value works.

Remove multiplies using without preserving order using `set`:

```
>>> {k: list(set(sum(v, []))) for k, v in n.items()}
{'a': ['c', 'b'], 'b': ['a', 'c'], 'c': ['b']}
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner solution(and not recommended) to this is :

```
{key: list(set([item for subarr in value for item in subarr])) for key, value in n.items()}
```

It is much harder to read though. If you really do not want to import anything, you can write a helper function.

```
def flat_and_unique_list(list_of_lists):
    return list(set([item for sub_list in list_of_lists for item in sub_list]))

{key: flat_and_unique_list(value) for key, value in n.items()}
```